# How can i raise DataGrid.LostFocus on RibbonButton.Click?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ribbon, focusmanager

The following code uses a ToolBar and correctly causes DataGrid.LostFocus (there by committing any uncomitted row-edits before the command is executed);

```
<Toolbar FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">
  <Button Command="{Binding CommandName}" />
</ToolBar>
<DataGrid ... />
```

However, I am now trying to do the same using the Ribbon (oct10 release), but the following does not cause DataGrid.LostFocus to be raised;

```
<Ribbon>
  <RibbonTab>
    <RibbonGroup FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">
      <RibbonButton Command="{Binding CommandName}" />
    </RibbonGroup>
  </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
<DataGrid ... />
```

How can I raise this event using the Ribbon?  I have tried moving the IsFocusScope through the other levels (Ribbon, RibbonTab, RibbonButton) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't like this due to the need for code behind, but in the absence of any other answers;

```
<Ribbon>
  <RibbonTab>
    <RibbonGroup>
      <RibbonButton Command="{Binding CommandName}" Click="dropFocus" />
    </RibbonGroup>
  </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
<Control IsTabStop="False" Name="focusControl"/>
<DataGrid ... />
```

And the code behind;

```
private void dropFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Keyboard.Focus(focusControl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Altough this question is over 6 years old, I want to post my solution too:
Just add an Eventhandler for PreviewMouseDown to the RibbonWin and set the focus to null...

```
private void RibbonWin_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, null);
}
```